# SQL - How can I perform the UPDATE statement on a specific position I have found in the code?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL. I have found the 2 rows that I need to update using the query below. 
Each person has a *salary*. I need to update their salary by £1000.
How do I use the UPDATE statement to update their specific records in the table?

```
SELECT fname, 
       lname, 
       telno, 
       Count (ownwerno) AS ownerNumberCount 
FROM   privateowner priv, 
       propertyforrent prop 
WHERE  priv.ownerno = prop.ownwerno 
GROUP  BY priv.fname, 
          priv.lname, 
          priv.telno 
HAVING Count(prop.ownwerno) >= ALL (SELECT Count(ownwerno) 
                                    FROM   propertyforrent 
                                    GROUP  BY ownwerno);
```

Comment: mention the rdbms you are using !!

Comment: If you have a `SELECT` statement that returns the employee IDs, you can use it as a subquery in `UPDATE ... FROM` to do a joined update.

Answer (score 3):

### Theory:

The "relational model theory" is a part of the mathematical "set theory". In mathematical sets there is no concept of ordering.

- a column is called an element;
- a row is called a tuple, it's one item containing a particular set of elements;
- a table is called a relation and it is a mathematical set containing members with a particular structure; the fact that you are grouping all of the elements (columns) together means they are related (firstname, lastname columns are *related* because of their owner);
- a foreign key between tables is (not a relation as common parlance would have it) just one of the normal forms;
- the result sets of selecting and filtering is also a relation (the structure may differ);

### Ordering:

You can always choose to explicitly order your results by a particular element (column), and due to implementation details most of the time "unordered" results will not be displayed randomly, they will be ordered as they are stored on disk (in the order they were created and subsequently read).

Because of the principle (there is no order, just a bag full of results) you need to either identify particular results by using the values in columns which are unique or identify groups of results by using values in columns which correctly discriminate the subgroup.

### Practice:

You can create a select as such:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE /*your filtering conditions*/;
```

With the same `WHERE` conditions you can allow the update clause to find what to update:

```
UPDATE table_name WHERE /*your filtering conditions*/;
```

---

If you have an identifier column:

```
SELECT identifier_column FROM table_name WHERE /*your filtering conditions*/;
```

With the same `WHERE` conditions you can allow the update clause to find what to update:

```
UPDATE table_name WHERE identifier_column = /*value*/ OR
                        identifier_column IN(/*list of values*/);
```

---

If you are selecting data from multiple tables you can either use a subquery or a join:

```
SELECT identifier_column FROM table_1 WHERE /*your filtering conditions*/;
```

Subquery:

```
UPDATE table_2
    SET /*update columns here*/
    WHERE indentifier_column IN(
        SELECT identifier_column FROM table_1 WHERE /*your filtering conditions*/
    );
```

Join:

```
UPDATE table_2
    LEFT JOIN table_1
        ON table_2.identifier_column = table_1.identifier_column
    SET /*update columns here*/
    WHERE /*your filtering conditions*/;
```